# Confusion with the meaning of a notation

Tags: notation, partial-differential-equations

An elliptic operator $L$ is called uniformly elliptic if  $a^{ij}(x)\xi _i\xi_j \ge \theta|\xi|^2$. 
What does this notation mean? All I can find about it is that it is some kind of summation notation or something. 
Can anyone explain me what it is?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Satisfied with the answer below?

Comment: @did : understood the definition but i am not able to appreciate ,why it should be defined that way ?

Comment: Well, for one thing, for the LHS to be a number, starting from a vector $(\xi_i)_i$ and a square matrix $(a_{ij}(x))_{ij}$. In the end, I do not know why you leave the question open.

Comment: @did : Sir , i didn't understand what u meant by leaving the question open .

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall \xi=(\xi_i)_i\qquad\sum\limits_{i,j}a^{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j \geqslant \theta\cdot|\xi|^2=\theta\cdot\sum\limits_i\xi_i^2$$

Comment: What is $\xi$ here actually thats my main problem to understand . can u help me ?

Comment: @Theorem an arbitrary vector with real components $\xi_i$

Comment: @Leonid Thanks.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev : Is that all sir ?? Thank you very much .

Comment: In other words, the matrix $A - \theta I$ is positive semidefinite, where $A_{ij} = a^{ij}(x)$.  For the operator to be uniformly elliptic on domain $\Omega$, you want there to be some $\theta > 0$ that makes this true for all $x \in \Omega$.